# How to make SQLAlchemy custom DDL be emitted after object inserted?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, materialized-views

I have a PostgreSQL Materialized View that calculates some data about Manufacturers.

I created a SQLAlchemy custom DDL command to refresh the view:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler

class RefreshMaterializedView(DDLElement):
    '''Target expected to be a view name string'''
    def __init__(self, concurrently):
        self.concurrently = concurrently

@compiler.compiles(RefreshMaterializedView)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
    if element.concurrently:
        return "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY %s" % (element.target)
    return "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW %s" % (element.target)

class ManufacturerMaterializedView(db.Model):
    @classmethod 
    def refresh(cls, concurrently=True, bind=db.session):
        RefreshMaterializedView(concurrently).execute(
                                target=cls.__table__.fullname, bind=bind)
```

Here's how I currently use it in my code:

```
db.session.add(new_manufacturer_instance)
ManufacturerMaterializedViewClass.refresh() # bound to the same session
db.session.flush()
# some other stuff
db.session.add(another_manufacturer_instance) # still in the same PostgreSQL transaction
ManufacturerMaterializedViewClass.refresh()
db.session.commit()
```

Desired behavior:

1. The materialized view is refreshed **after** the new_manufacturer_instance is created.
2. I can repeatedly insert new manufacturers and call `ManufacturerMaterializedViewClass.refresh()` multiple times within the same session, but the refresh will only be emitted once, at the end of the session after all the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements for all objects have been emitted. Other object types affect the output of this materialized view, so this refresh statement needs to be emitted after those objects are modified.

Here's what's currently happening when I view the Flask-Sqlalchemy query log using `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True`:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> ManufacturerFactory() # creates a new manufacturer instance and adds it to the session
  <Manufacturer #None:'est0'>
>>> ManufacturerMV.refresh()
  2015-11-29 13:33:44,811 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
  2015-11-29 13:33:44,812 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY manufacturer_mv
  2015-11-29 13:33:44,812 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
>>> db.session.flush()
  2015-11-29 13:34:13,745 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO manufacturer (name, website, logo, time_updated) VALUES (%(name)s, %(website)s, %(logo)s, %(time_updated)s) RETURNING manufacturer.id
  2015-11-29 13:34:13,745 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'logo': '/static/images/16-rc_gear_essential.jpg', 'website': 'http://hermann.com/', 'time_updated': None, 'name': 'est0'}
>>>> db.session.commit()
  2015-11-29 13:42:58,160 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

As you can see, calling `refresh()` immediately issues SQL to the DB, even before a `session.flush()`, pre-empting any additional insert/update statements. However, the DDL isn't actually executed by PostgreSQL until `session.commit()` closes the transaction.

How should I modify my DDL/classmethod to achieve my desired behavior?

I looked at the [ORM events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#) but wasn't quite sure how to leverage them for my use case. I don't want a refresh called on every `session.commit()` emitted by my application. The refreshing this particular view is a fairly expensive operation, so it should only happen when I actually called `refresh()` within the current transaction/`session`.